# Eclipse crashes on creating a new Remote Java Application

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

Does anyone know what is happening here?

[image: Remote Java Application]

I need to debug something specific on the server side but I can't create the Remote Java application.

Eclipse Juno and Windows 10. Java 1.8.0_66-b18